# Install Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu not using RVM?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rvm

Is it possible to install Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu not using RVM?

Comment: why don't you want to use rvm?

Comment: @jshen: I mainly use Javascript/node. I just want to install ruby/python/php to be able to use some applications, but I don't write any code in these languages, so I don't need to switch to another ruby version.

Answer (score 2):

On current versions of Ubuntu, `aptitude install ruby1.9.1` installs YARV 1.9.2-p0.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install Ruby from source. Depending on how you configure it it can go into /usr/local/bin, which is the default, or to a directory you specify using the --PREFIX option.

I'd recommend using RVM though. It does a great job for an individual developer, and supports systemwide configurations if you're the admin. If you're after a system-wide config this might help, especially the section at the bottom discussing the advantages. http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/